# How to cast columns in psycopg2's excluded values insert

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to update a table using 2 columns of a pandas dataframe. Here is my code:

```
query = """
    update table_1 m
    set column_1 = e.column_1
    from (VALUES %s) AS e (column_2, column_1) 
    where m.column_2= e.column_2::text"""


args = (('random_value_2','2022-11-15T13:04:18.844Z'), ('random_value_1','2022-11-15T13:04:18.844Z'))

psycopg2.extras.execute_values(
        cur, query, args, template=None, page_size=100
        )
```

When I run this code, I get the error:

```
psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: column "column_1" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type record
LINE 3:     set column_1= e.column_1
```

How to cast str / python datetime to timestamp with timezone in psycopg2?

Comment: Have you tried casting like this `set column_1 = e.column_1::timestamptz`?

Comment: Yes, gives: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject: type "timestampz"

Comment: timestamptz, not timestampz (the t is missing)

Comment: try to use [to_timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) in the expression or anywhere it generates an error `column_1 = (to_timestamp(e.column_1, 'MM/DD/YY hh24:mi')`

Comment: @user3738870, cannot cast type record to timestamp with time zone. I guess somehow it should be casted using psycopg2's functions.

Comment: No, it's working for me at least. You might be passing the data in a different way than in the code in your question. You mention a "pandas dataframe" but what you have in that code is just a tuple of tuples.

Comment: @ellhe-blaster, psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function to_timestamp(record, unknown) does not exist

Comment: @user3738870, turning dataframe's columns to tuple of tuples and those are the tuples I am passing.

Comment: Then probably the error is in that transformation. When you're passing the parameters in the same way as in the code in your question, it's working.

Comment: @user3738870 right, there was a problem. Now it worked, thanks.

Comment: Great, for the future, please include any related code that could be causing the issue  in your Stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 0):

Table creation and initial data entry.

```
create table table_1 (column_1 timestamp, column_2 varchar);

insert into table_1 values (current_timestamp,'random_value_2'), (current_timestamp, 'random_value_1');

select * from table_1;
          column_1          |    column_2    
----------------------------+----------------
 11/16/2022 08:00:58.309285 | random_value_2
 11/16/2022 08:00:58.309285 | random_value_1
```

Python code as you show:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values 

con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres', port=5432)
cur = con.cursor()

args = (('random_value_2','2022-11-15T13:04:18.844Z'), ('random_value_1','2022-11-15T13:04:18.844Z'))

query = """
    update table_1 m
    set column_1 = e.column_1
    from (VALUES %s) AS e (column_2, column_1) 
    where m.column_2= e.column_2::text"""

execute_values(
        cur, query, args, template=None, page_size=100
        )

DatatypeMismatch: column "column_1" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text
LINE 3:     set column_1 = e.column_1

con.rollback()
```

The error is different in that expression that fails is text not a record. This implies you are actually doing something different.

Corrected code, putting in explicit cast to timestamp:

```
query = """
    update table_1 m
    set column_1 = e.column_1::timestamp
    from (VALUES %s) AS e (column_2, column_1) 
    where m.column_2= e.column_2::text"""

execute_values(
        cur, query, args, template=None, page_size=100
        )

con.commit()
```

Select from table:

```
select * from table_1;
          column_1          |    column_2    
----------------------------+----------------
 11/16/2022 08:00:58.309285 | random_value_2
 11/16/2022 08:00:58.309285 | random_value_1
```